# Xamarin's Buttons issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I've only recently started Xamarin and I'm having trouble figuring out how to design a few blocks. I'm trying to create some simple buttons to navigate with and it was decent (picture 2). But as soon as I tried binding it to a data, the design basically ran off (picture 1). Any suggestions?

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug6ah.png)

[Image of the attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn4bI.png)

Below are the codes for picture 1:

```
            <ListView x:Name="displayCourses" ItemsSource="{Binding CourseName}">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <!--<Button Text="{Binding CourseName}" BackgroundColor="#ea3e15" 
                                    CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="290" HeightRequest="130"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="26" Clicked="NextPage"
                                    />-->
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Button Text="{Binding CourseName}" BackgroundColor="#ea3e15" TextColor="#fff"
                                CornerRadius="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="26"
                                />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

CS codes linking the data together

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            displayCourses.ItemsSource = await firebaseHelper.GetCourses();
        }

        public async Task<List<Course>> GetCourses()
        {
            FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://pra-ece32-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
            return (await firebase
                .Child("Courses")
                .OnceAsync<Course>()).Select(item => new Course
                {
                    CourseName = item.Object.CourseName,
                    CourseID = item.Object.CourseID,
                    ExamDate = item.Object.ExamDate,
                }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: `ItemsSource` needs to be an `IEnumerable<T>` that is the collection of data objects to display in your list.  Then the `Text` property of your `Button` should be bound to a property of the class `T`.  There are numerous examples and samples that demonstrate how to use a ListView on the Xamarin site.

Comment: @Jason There's no problem regarding linking the data from the CS file to the XAML file as the `ItemsSource` and the `Text` property are already loaded. I'm having trouble on designing the page when the data is already loaded (picture 1) as it automatically decides to not follow the properties that I've set from picture 2.

Comment: Are you also setting ItemsSource in the code behind?  And please post the code for your model class

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that question, but I've already updated the post with the codes linking the data together.

Comment: If you are talking about the buttons being cut off, you need to specify a RowHeight for your listView

Comment: @Jason I was not aware of that property and I thank you for it, solved it for me. I thought there was no way to adjust the height and width of the `ListView` property since they don't have the `WidthRequest` or `HeightRequest` property. Forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of a row inside the listview will always take up the entire width of the listview itself. There is no way to have extra space between the end of a Row and the edge of the listview, nor would that make any sense.

But you can use Grid to meet your requirement. Please set ListView HasUnevenRow="True" to automatically size row height to fit content.

```
<ListView
            x:Name="displayCourses"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding courses}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="#ea3e15"
                                CornerRadius="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="26"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                Text="{Binding coursename}"
                                TextColor="#fff"
                                WidthRequest="200" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

[image]